# Проблема в архитектуре БД для бронирования билетов в кинотеатр

Tags: база-данных, инспекция-кода, проектирование

Привет.

Делаю проект по бронированию билетов на киносеанс. Использую spring boot + jpa + hibernate на java (к слову). Базу спроектировал - cinema_old.[image: Вариант схемы номер 1] Все вроде бы ок. У кинотеатра cinema есть схема мест cinema_schema, у сеанса seance  есть ссылка на кинотеатр и фильм movie, у фильма есть жанр. Есть сущность место place, которые создаются на определенный сеанс. Есть пользователь customer. Есть бронь booking, которая создается определенным пользователем на определенные места. Но при создании из кода брони booking не подтягивается место place - требует в сущности place ссылку на бронь booking.

Затем переделал на cinema_new. [image: Вариант схемы номер 2] Но что-то понимаю, что немного запутался в связи бронь - билет.

Так вот, слезно прошу взглянуть опытным взглядом на новую схему - правильно я исправил или может наведете на путь истинный?

Заранее благодарю за ответы -))

Comment: какова практическая ценность сущности `movies-genre`?

Comment: @Anatol очевидно же, что это не сущность, а развязка для MtM-отношения

Comment: Кстати, я бы в этой развязке оба атрибута сделал ключевыми.

Comment: @PavelMayorov действительно, очевидно. Не обратил внимания на это, тк в тексте вопроса говорится *у фильма есть жанр*

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, у вас каждое место может быть забронировано в каждый момент времени только 1 раз. Поэтому, если у вас нет желания превращать свою таблицу booking в темпоральную (т.е. хранящую полную историю всех бронирований и снятий бронирования), либо сделать между таблицами связь "один к одному", либо вовсе объединить таблицы place и booking.

Связь "один к одному" делается через связь первичных ключей. Будьте внимательны: зависимый первичный ключ в такой связке не должен быть автогенерируемым!

Что же до ошибок вида *"но при создании из кода брони booking не подтягивается место place - требует в сущности place ссылку на бронь booking"* - их надо начинать решать не в рамках схемы БД, а в рамках того инструмента с которым что-то не получается.

PS Пожалуйста, выбирайте для названий таблиц слова во множественном числе: "cinema_schemas", "places", "bookings", "movies", "genres".

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, вы писали: "Насколько я понимаю, у вас каждое место может быть забронировано в каждый момент времени только 1 раз" - Ну да, а разве может быть по-другому? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример -))

Comment: "Пожалуйста, выбирайте для названий таблиц слова во множественном числе" - резко против этой рекомендации. Пожалуйста, не делайте так. Когда объектов БД будет действительно много (сотни и тысячи таблиц, да и на десятках уже заметно), непременно захочется придумать систему наименования объектов (констрейнтов, сиквенсов, триггеров и т. д.) - вот тут вы и хлебнете "множественного числа".

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, вы писали:  "Поэтому, если у вас нет желания превращать свою таблицу booking в темпоральную (т.е. хранящую полную историю всех бронирований и снятий бронирования)". У меня в соответствии с бизнес-логикой если юзер будет отменять бронь, то соответствующие записи из таблицы booking будут удаляться.

Comment: @Dmitry чего именно хлебну?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это рекомендация для ТС. Вопрос очевидно холиварный, если вас всё устраивает - то у вас всё ок. Я же склонен рассматривать предложение использовать множественное число как антирекомендацию, о чем и написал.